# Commands that require internet connection have some delay

Tags: ubuntu, internet, internet-connection

**Problem: I get some delay with internet connection in some applications.** E.g:

- In Firefox, when I search something or go on a website, it waits at first. This is happening in every web page. Then it loads normally. But this does not happen with Google Chrome.
- Similarly, when I run an `apt install` command or anything similar, it waits at first, then installs (or downloads) it normally.
- Similarly, when I run a `pip install` command (python), it waits at first, then proceeds normally.

Similarly in `git fetch` commands, etc. They all wait for like 10-15 seconds.

But interestingly, apps like Discord, MS Teams runs normally.

What could be the problem?

The first thing came into my mind is my DNS settings. I have checked it and it was set manual instead of automatic. I suppose an app changed it. I set it to auto, logged out and in. But the problem continues.

**Edit 2:** Commands run normally (fast) when I run them again in the same terminal after the first try.

**Edit 1:** Add Network developer tab for YouTube in Firefox (gif).

[image]

**Edit 3:** `strace git fetch`. It waits on line 239:
`read(5, "000e", 4)                      = 4`

See the trace: https://pastebin.com/c9Kvn9f3

[image]

**Edit 4:** YouTube timings:
[image]

**Edit 5:** resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search --
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way to gather more information is to use the `Network` tab in the Firefox Developer tools. If that doesn't give any insight, you can use `strace` to gather more info for the command line tools.

Comment: @mtak Thanks, I have added a gif of Network tab. You can see the behaviour. I will try strace too.

Comment: In the Network tab; click the first line (youtube.com) and then in the pop-up, check the `Timings` tab and post a screenshot of that

Comment: I have added strace output too.

Comment: For strace, the GIF is pretty useless. Please just dump as text, possibly using pastebin or something if it's too much.

Comment: Added timings and updated strace part. @mtak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output provided, I'm going to guess that one of your DNS servers isn't responding or is returning an invalid response. I am not sure where the `blocked` state comes from, but 15 seconds for DNS resolution is *way* too long.

This could be the DNS server inside your system. Since you didn't specify the Ubuntu version, this could be dnsmasq or systemd-resolved. An easy way to check this is to bypass it completely.

Replace the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` with the following:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

And try again. Note that this is not a permanent fix, as `/etc/resolv.conf` will most likely (again, Ubuntu-version dependent) be changed by one of the services mentioned above.

The problem could also be caused by one of your upstream DNS servers not responding (or giving an invalid response). To test this, use the nameservers mentioned above in your configuration. They should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My OS is actually Pop!_OS 22.04, an Ubuntu dist. I will try this asap.

Comment: It worked! But I don't really know what caused this. Is it safe if I change it every time or at system startup? I will add the contents of resolv.conf to the question.

Comment: It's probably your DHCP server giving out a non-functioning DNS server's address. The best fix would be to fix the DHCP server. If you can't, there are guides on the internet that tell you how to set static DNS in systemd-resolved (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442598/how-to-configure-systemd-resolved-and-systemd-networkd-to-use-local-dns-server-f for example)